# Проблема с русскими символами в составе ссылки

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Я парсил сайт в своём приложении с помощью библиотеки Jsoup и столкнулся с проблемой. Некоторые ссылки содержали в себе части на кириллице(параметр get-запроса), но работали нормально, контент парсился. Но в один момент всё перестало работать. Jsoup стал игнорировать часть ссылки, которая содержала в себе кириллицу. Я вывел эти ссылки в лог: часть ссылки на латинице отображалась нормально, кириллица - как обычный текст.
Я решил попробовать кодировать кириллическую часть ссылки в utf-8 с помощью URLEncoder как советуют в интернете. Теперь ссылка в логе отображалась полностью и открывалась в браузере на компьютере (вместо кириллицы были проценты с символами), но в приложении всё равно ничего не парсилось.
Самое странное, что сначала всё работало, и я даже не задумывался о кодировке. Проблемы начались после того, как я подключил к приложению базу данных SQLite и использовал её функции. Может это как-то могло повлиять?

```
mCurrentGroup = mSharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_group), ""); //берём кириллическое значение
    try{
        mCurrentGroup = URLEncoder.encode(mCurrentGroup, "utf-8");
    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mCurrentLink = mLinkMain.concat(mCurrentGroup).concat(PLUS_WEEK).concat(mWeek);//соединяем с остальным на латинице
```

Подключение в ссылки в Jsoup:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(mLink).get(); //где mLink - "собранная ссылка mCurrentLink"
```

Comment: Приведенных данных не достаточно, чтобы сделать какие-то выводы о проблеме. Некоторые ссылки в входных текстах хранились в неправильном формате, когда вместо urlencode в utf-8 шли сами символы? Все работало до того, как вы начали работать с SQLite, или еще раньше сломалось (из последовательности ответа так следует). Пооднозначней как бы надо.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov до того как я начал работать с sqlite всё работало без всяких URLEncoder'ов

Comment: Вы ссылку из записей базы формируете? Может там проблема с кодировками?

Comment: @woesss нет, не из записей. Вся латинская часть ссылки просто string-переменные. Кириллическая часть получается парсингом другой страницы, записывается в sharedpreferences и считывается оттуда. Затем вставляется в общую ссылку

Comment: Попробуйте HTML получать не средствами `JSOUP`, но другой либой. Например `OkHttp` - может в `JSOUP` проблема - я с чем-то таким сталкивался в одной из либ для парсинга. Вроде она и эта пользуют один и тот же (багованный в данном случае) способ получения данных из сети (устаревшую либу).

Comment: JSOUP свежей версии сам кодирует url и предварительная кодировка только усугубляет проблему. И если вдруг сервер выдаёт переадресацию с закодированным адресом JSOUP кодирует его повторно, что естественно приводит к недоразумениям.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб В итоге решил проблему тем, что обновил версию используемой библиотеки с 1.10.2 на 1.10.3. Это очень странно если честно. Сначала-то всё работало и на старой версии.